# Matplotlib bar graph not drawing borders/edges

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code for my bar graph.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
ax1.bar(edges2, Nnorm, width=0.02, edgecolor='green', linewidth=20)
```

I thought that should make my bar graph have green edges.  But it does not.  It makes one bar on the far left green.  What am I doing wrong?  Facecolor works.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, [this is a bug in matplotlib 2.1](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9351). It is fixed in matplotlib version 2.2.

As of now a workaround is to set the edgecolor and linewidth for each bar individually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bars = plt.bar(range(4), [3,4,1,5])
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_edgecolor("green")
    bar.set_linewidth(20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Unfortunate bug, but that work around works great.  Thanks! I'll keep an eye out for an update.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained this is a [matplotlib bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9351). However, it's only a missing broadcast of the edgecolor, so here's a more compact workaround:

```
plt.bar(x, y, linewidth=20, edgecolor=['g']*len(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to pass an alpha parameter:

```
plt.bar(range(4), [3,4,1,5], alpha=1, edgecolor='k', linewidth=20)
```

**NOTE:** This only works if the edgecolor you are setting is black, otherwise the first column will have the correct edgecolor and the rest will be black