# formatting to group of bars using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend

I am trying to learn python mainly for plotting. Here is my sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
x=np.arange(len(a[0]))
width=0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
patterns=['/','\\','*']

for bar in a:
    ax.bar(x,bar,width,edgecolor='black',color='lightgray', hatch=patterns.pop(0))
    x=x+width

plt.show()
```

Now the problem is that, I need *black* edge colour for all bars as well as given *hatch patter*. However, the formatting is applied to first set of bars only. Here is my output. (I am using python3).

[image]

What's missing here or what's wrong? I have looked around but did not find any fix.

**Update:**
I have tried different options :python2, python3 and pdf/png. Here are results

- python2 png --fine
- python3 png -- shown above
- python2 pdf -- see [image: this]
- python3 pdf -- see [image: this]

I have also tried 'backend' as `matplotlib.use('Agg')`. I have update my `matplotlib` version (2.1.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks something's wrong with edgecolor tuple's alpha value. Set it to 1 will solve the problem.

Comment: right, but I have exactly three type of bars, i.e. first bar -- forward slash, second bar --backward slash and lastly starts. Instead of pop, doing patters[i] will return same.

Comment: what about border colour of each bar?

Comment: Edited, there might be better solutions with itertools package.

Comment: your edit returns same result as I have pasted here.

Comment: Actually your original code works fine in my jupyter note book. Did you miss anything?

Comment: Damm... it works without any prob for python2. Thanks for hint.

Comment: Then it might be an iterator thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158195/discussion-between-haochen-wu-and-amit).

Answer (score 4):

There is a [current issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9351) in matplotlib 2.1 that only the first bar's edgecolor is applied. The same for the hatch, see [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9496).  Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814229/matplotlib-bar-graph-not-drawing-borders-edges).

It may be that you are using matplotlib 2.1 for python3 but not for python2, hence in python2 it works for you. If I run your code in python 2 with matplotlib 2.1 I get the same undesired behaviour.

The issue will be fixed, once matplotlib 2.1.1 is released.

In the meantime, a workaround is to set the edgecolor and hatch on the individual bars:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
x=np.arange(len(a[0]))
width=0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
patterns=['/','\\','*']

for y in a:
    bars = ax.bar(x,y,width,color='lightgray')
    hatch= patterns.pop(0)
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_edgecolor("black")
        bar.set_hatch(hatch)
    x=x+width

plt.show()
```

[image]